# OneSignal @Override not applicable to type

Tags: java, android, onesignal

{Novice Android Developer}

I am following [this tutorial](http://androidmkab.com/2016/04/20/how-to-add-onesignal-com-push-notifications-to-your-android-app/) regarding adding OneSignal Push notifications to my application. One thing that I am having difficulty with is the adding of the MainActivity.java code found at the end of the tutorial. I receive multiple errors.

I would be much obliged if someone would be able to assist me with this last portion of OneSignal integration. The main issue I am having is the placement of this code in regards to what is already in the MainActivity and what the tutorial mentions.

When I insert the code where the tutorial says, I receive an error which says 
@Override not applicable to type

[GitHub Repo of Project](https://github.com/AbanoubG/thecopticorthodoxfaith/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/copticchurch/library/discoverorthodoxy/activities/main/MainActivity.java)

```
// This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it or one is received while the app is running.
private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
    @Override
    public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {
        try {
            if (additionalData != null) {
                if (additionalData.has("actionSelected"))
                    Log.d("OneSignalExample", "OneSignal notification button with id " + additionalData.getString("actionSelected") + " pressed");

                Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Full additionalData:\n" + additionalData.toString());
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the code I am referring to.

*Note
I omitted other parts of the tutorial in the code for the reason that I am aware of that portion of the tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means either the name of the function or the parameters are not correct.  Or that function doesn't exist in the library at all.  According to OneSignal's docs, the correct signature is

```
public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result)
```

So either that tutorial is for a different version or the tutorial was never working.

Comment: Could you link to what doc you are referring to? Tutorial worked fine for 2 other projects that use OneSignal successfully

Comment: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationopenedhandler-